# Resistor in series with capacitor or inductor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, low-pass

Why do we put resistors in series with capacitors or inductors in single time constant circuits?

In this diagram

[image: Circuit]

we see a resistor connected in series with a capacitor. This could act as a low-pass network.

My question is: is there a specific reason why the resistor is added? Or is it just there to model the resistance of the metal wire?

Because if I was designing a low-pass circuit, why would I add the resistor? Wouldn't it just waste power?

Comment: For an ideal voltage source with the capacitor in place and no series resistance, the voltage on the capacitor is just equal to the voltage source voltage. What use is that?

Comment: What @James said, plus if you are designing a low-pass circuit, typically you want to PASS some band of low frequencies and attenuate higher ones.  So if you don't control the time constant (RC) how can you control your passband?

Comment: You can't filter anything with just an ideal capacitor. If you're concerned about power losses (e.g. filtering power lines, not signals) you use an LC filter instead of an RC one, which has no dissipative elements and thus no power loss (assuming ideal conditions, of course).

Answer (score 3):

The circuit provided is the definitive 1st order low pass filter. The unwanted frequencies are dropped across the resistor. If R is zero then there would be no filtering at all.

The time constant that you refer to is the product of R and C. If R is zero then so is the time constant.

The corner frequency is $$f_{0}=\frac{1}{2\pi RC} $$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Saving power is a good idea but not at the expense of making the circuit redundant.

Comment: Please add a citation or link for the graphic you copied into your answer. That is the policy for answers on this site.